# ヘルプセンターの「モデレーター ツールへのアクセス」を改善したい

Tags: バグ, ヘルプ

ヘルプセンターの [モデレーター ツールへのアクセス](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) 内で「ツール」へのアクセス方法を説明する段落がありますが、現在貼り付けられている画像がかなり古く、また切り抜かれた範囲が小さいため、慣れたユーザーでも一見しただけではどこを指しているのかが分かりづらい状態です。

この部分を "日本語版" における最新の画像で差し替えたいです。(ついでなので「インラインタグ編集」の部分も)

---

**日本語版での画像:**

[image]

**英語版での画像:**

[image]